# How to write to Cross domain localstorage without making any change in other domain

Tags: javascript, local-storage, cross-domain

Currently i am trying to achieve one functionality where I have 2 sites like [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) and other is https://excel.officeapps/live.com. Now i am trying to set some Key-value in second site(https://excel.officeapps/live.com) localstorage by hitting some button in first site.

After researching on this I Came to know it is Cross domain localstorage concept and only below approach i found everywhere.

https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/

But the only issue i found here that i don't have control over second site so i can receive message and set it in localstorage of it. Can someone suggest on it whether it is even possible or not and if yes what alternate approach i can take.

Comment: Does that seem like a good security thing? Answer is No.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write data into localStorage belonging to sites that you don't control.

The possibilities for vandalism (and worse) would be immense.